# type parameter in template<typename T> int compare(const T&, const T&)

Tags: c++, templates

if defining the following function template

```
template<typename T>
int compare(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
{
    // body 
}
```

then

```
const char* p1 = "abc";
const char* p2 = "efg";
compare(p1, p2);
```

why does the compiler deduce T as `const char*`(so the type of lhs and rhs is `const char* const &` ) not `char*`(so the type of lhs and rhs is `const char* &`)?

Comment: `T` is deduced to be `const char*& `, the two consts were collapsed together by the compiler. You should declare your function to take `const T*` if you want the compiler to not deduce a reference to a pointer.

Comment: Leading const is misleading. And argument deduction does not proceed like macro substitution.

Comment: After reading a part of Effective Modern C++, I know why now.

Comment: @TanveerBadar IMO, since `T = const char*`, a pointer to `const char`, for `const T`, the base type is a pointer type which the `const` in `const T` modifies. That is the pointer is constant. With regard to `&`, read from right to left, it is a reference to a pointer to `const char`. Hence, the type of `lhs` and `rhs` is `const char* const &`.